# Виджет комментариев в React в Functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не получается написать локальное добавление комментария после нажатия на кнопку "Добавить". С сервером взаимодействует нормально, после обновления страницы коммент появляется, а как сделать, чтобы комментарий отобразился сразу? Код прикрепляю ниже

```
const Comments = () => {

  let textInput = React.createRef()

    const { isAuthorized } = useContext(MyContext)

    const { videoIdCC, isFetching, userData } = useContext(WatchContext)


    console.log(videoIdCC, )

    const addComment = () =>{
        if(!isAuthorized) return window.location.href = '/logreg1';
        let commentForm = document.forms["commentForm"];
        let commentText = commentForm.elements["commentText"].value;
        fetch("/api/comments/" + videoIdCC,
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"data": commentText})
        }).then (res=>res.json())
        .then(result=>{console.log(result)})

    }

    // const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(true);
    let [comments, setComments] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {

        fetch('/api/comments/' + videoIdCC)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
            setComments(comments = result)
            // setIsFetching(!isFetching)
        })
    }, [])



        if(isFetching){
            return <> Loading...</>
        }
        else return (

            <>

                <div className="CommentForm">
                        <form id="commentForm">
                            <div className="ProfileImg">
                                <img
                                    width={"48"}
                                    height={"48"}
                                    //src={skeleton}
                                    id={"cha-img"}
                                    alt={""}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <textarea id="commentText" type="text" placeholder="Добавить комментарий" className="InputComment" ref={textInput}></textarea>
                            <div className="ccd">
                                <Button onClick={ e => { e.preventDefault(); addComment(); }}>Добавить</Button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                <div className="Comments">
                    {Object.keys(comments).map(key => (
                    <div key={key} className="CommentInfo">
                        <div className="ProfileImg">
                            <img
                                width={"48"}
                                height={"48"}
                                src={""}
                                id={"cha-img"}
                                alt={""}
                            />
                        </div>
                        {console.log(comments[key])}

                        <div className="CommentText">
                            <div className="CommentatorNick">
                            {/* {(comments[key].commentatorID).includes(userData?._id)} */}
                                {comments[key].commentatorID}
                            </div>
                            {/* {comment} */}
                            
                            {comments[key].data}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ))}
                </div>

            </>
        )
    }
```

Comment: После добавления комментария `comments` не меняется, так как `setComments` вызывается только в эффекте, а эффект срабатывает только один раз при первом рендере.

Answer (score 0):

Я переписал компоненту по принципу подсказки от p1uton, однако все равно не обновляются комментарии

````
    
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import './Comments.scss';
import { WatchContext } from '../WatchContext'
import {MyContext} from "../../../MyContext";


const Comments = () => {

    const { isAuthorized } = useContext(MyContext)

    const { videoIdCC, isFetching, userData } = useContext(WatchContext)
    let [comments, setComments] = useState({});


    const addComment = () =>{
        if(!isAuthorized) return window.location.href = '/logreg1';
        let commentForm = document.forms["commentForm"];
        let commentText = commentForm.elements["commentText"].value;
        fetch("/api/comments/" + videoIdCC,
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"data": commentText})
        })
        const newComment = {
            commentatorID: userData._id,
            data: commentText
        }
        let allComments = comments
        allComments.push(newComment)
        // comments.push(newComment)
        setComments(allComments)
    }


    useEffect(() => {

        fetch('/api/comments/' + videoIdCC)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
            setComments(comments = result)
            // setIsFetching(!isFetching)
        })
    }, [])



        if(isFetching){
            return <> Loading...</>
        }
        else return (

            <>

                <div className="CommentForm">
                        <form id="commentForm">
                            <div className="ProfileImg">
                                <img
                                    width={"48"}
                                    height={"48"}
                                    //src={skeleton}
                                    id={"cha-img"}
                                    alt={""}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <textarea id="commentText" type="text" placeholder="Добавить комментарий" className="InputComment"></textarea>
                            <div className="ccd">
                                <Button onClick={ e => { e.preventDefault(); addComment(); }}>Добавить</Button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                <div className="Comments">
                    {Object.keys(comments).map(key => (
                    <div key={key} className="CommentInfo">
                        <div className="ProfileImg">
                            <img
                                width={"48"}
                                height={"48"}
                                src={""}
                                id={"cha-img"}
                                alt={""}
                            />
                        </div>
                        {console.log(comments[key])}

                        <div className="CommentText">
                            <div className="CommentatorNick">
                            {/* {(comments[key].commentatorID).includes(userData?._id)} */}
                                {comments[key].commentatorID}
                            </div>
                            {comments[key].data}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ))}
                </div>

            </>
        )
    }


export default withRouter(Comments);```
````